# How to use Xquery without xml-database

Tags: xquery

I am experimenting with Xquery and have used sedna and basex as xml-databases.
All the examples I have found on internet depend on a database so all the connections need a username/password. What I need however is to use Xquery in combination with just a XML-file (and no database).

What is the best way to create a connection to a file and execute a query?

Answer (score 4):

BaseX provides various operating modes. It can e.g. be used as command-line tool (see http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Startup_Options)...

```
basex -i input.xml "/your/query"
```

..or from within Java (see e.g. https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/query/RunQueries.java).

In all cases, there is no need to explicitly create database instances.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the XQuery command line tools supplied with [XmlPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/doc/1.0/xquery-command-line-reference.htm) or Saxon.